# Error:TypeError: Cannot find function getValue in object function mergeAcross

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I tried to get the value of each cell in a range of cells and got this error:

> 'Error:TypeError: Cannot find function getValue in object function mergeAcross'.

I've read the documentation of `mergeAcross()` and didn't understand what it had to do with my problem. I've used the opposite function of `mergeAcross()` on the `dataRange` variable, the `breakApart()` function and it didn't work as well. I have also tried creating a variable with the `dataRange` values and using it in the for loop, but then I can't get the row where the value is.

```
var Ssheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = Ssheet.getSheets()[0];
var dataRange = sheet.getRange('B2:B100');
for (var ncell in dataRange){
  if (!dataRange[ncell].getValue()){
    break
  }
  var othercellVa = sheet.getRange(dataRange[ncell].getRow(),13).getValue(); 
  // I need to get the row of the value I'm reading
  Logger.log(dataRange[ncell].getValue());
}
```

I should get the cell values logged, but instead I'm getting the error described above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A single column is still a two dimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function myFunction() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh=ss.getSheets()[0];//gets the left sheet
var rg=sh.getRange('B2:B100');
var vA=rg.getValues();  
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(!vA[i][0])  {
      break;//if null
    }
  }
  Logger.log(vA);
}
```

I'm just trying to point out that in your code dataRange has no values a range is simply a cell or a collection of adjacent cell.  The object has no values.  You can test it with Object.values(dataRange) and you will see that it only has methods.  So it makes no sense to use this form dataRange[ncell] because it contains no values and all of it's keys are methods.  So if you're look for the rows and columns of each value in this range first you have to get the values with dataRange.getValues() and now you have a two dimensional array.  The following example will display row and column values for each cell in that column.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet177');
  var rg=sh.getRange('B2:B100');
  var vA=rg.getValues();  
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(!vA[i][0])  {
      Logger.log('no value row: %s col: %s',rg.getRow() + i, rg.getColumn());
      continue;//if null
    }else{
      Logger.log('value: %s row: %s col: %s',vA[i][0],rg.getRow() + i, rg.getColumn());
    }
  }
}
```